# Distinct selection of a field in views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I created a view in the views module which displays the blogs posted on my site having ONE tag. (Each blog has only 1 tag)

Is it possible to do a 'distinct' argument to only display every tag in this list once?

Basically, I wish to get a view with each tag's latest post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to select only tag field in field list, and then check "Distinct" in advance panel of view. Or use aggregation in that panel.